# Rails - cannot display an image uploaded to Amazon S3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, image, amazon-s3, paperclip

I have these two models:

**user:**

```
has_many :commercials, :dependent => :destroy, :inverse_of => :user
```

**commercial:**

```
  belongs_to :user, :inverse_of => :commercials

  has_attached_file :image,
    :styles => { :medium => "400x400",
                 :thumb  => "50x50>" }
```

I just uploaded one image, the image is successfully uploaded to Amazon S3 and saved into the database.
But how to display it?

I tried:

```
<%= image_tag @user.adverts(:medium) %>
```

or

```
<%= image_tag @user.adverts.medium.url %>
```

But none of above is working...

Comment: Where does `adverts` come from? All your code talks about is `commercials`. So should it not be something like `@user.commercials.first.image.url`?

Comment: Just a typo... please, add this as an answer I will mark you, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not `adverts`, but `commercials`? So should it not be something like:

```
@user.commercials.first.image.url
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `foo` as the name of the commercial instance

```
<%= image_tag foo.image.url(:medium) %>
```